# how to make an image disappear by clicking on word?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a small game . I have four pics of animals and blow the pic i have four names . what the game suppose to do is when the users click on right image and right name both the image and the name has to disappear. But in my case just the image disappear. Any help really appreciate it .

```js
var selectedImage;
var selectedName;

//Change the value of the selectedImage and check the values
function selectImage(event){
  selectedImage = event.target;
  checkValues();
}

//Change the value of the selectedName and check the values
function selectName(event){
  selectedName = event.target;
  checkValues();
}


function checkValues() {
console.log(selectedImage);
console.log(selectedName);
//Check if both values are selected
  if (!selectedImage || selectedImage == 'undefined' || !selectedName || selectedName == 'undefined'){
    return ;
  }
//Check if values are equals
  if (selectedImage.value == selectedName.value) {
    alert("good");
//remove the button and the image
    selectedImage.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    selectedName.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    alert("no");
  }
//Reset the selected image and name.
  selectedImage = 'undefined';
  selectedName = 'undefined';
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="animals" id="cow" class="input-hidden" value="cow"/>
        <label for="cow">
            <img src="images/cow.jpg" onclick="this.style.display='none';"  alt=""/>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" name="animals" onclick="this.style.display='none';" id="dog" class="input-hidden" value="dog"/>
        <label for="dog">
            <img src="images/dog.jpg" alt=""/>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" name="animals" onclick="this.style.display='none';" id="horse" class="input-hidden" value="horse"/>
        <label for="horse">
            <img src="images/horse.jpg" alt=""/>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" name="animals" onclick="this.style.display='none';" id="pig" class="input-hidden" value="pig"/>
        <label for="pig">
            <img src="images/pig.jpg" alt=""/>
        </label>

    </form>

</div>     

    <div class="content">


<button type="button" onclick="this.style.display='none';image_select2()" value="dog" id="dog_t">Chien</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="this.style.display='none';image_select()" value="cow" id="cow_t">Vache</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="this.style.display='none';image_select4()" value="pig" id="pig_t">Cochon</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="this.style.display='none';image_select3()" value="horse" id="horse_t">Cheval</button> 


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the code in the button click, add to each of the JavaScript inside the if statement like this:

```
if (pic4 == text4) {
    Text4.style.display = 'none'
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Pintang for taking your time to answer my question.Unfortunately i tired what you wrote but it did not work . :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is working and I think simpler snippet of what your are trying to achieve.

You have to variables, one that represent the selected image, and an other that represents the selected button. When you click on any Image that will change the value of `selectedImage`, and when you click on a button that will change the value of `selectedName`. After the value change, the `checkValues` function check if the two values are selected and equal.

```js
var selectedImage;
var selectedName;

//Change the value of the selectedImage and check the values
function selectImage(event){
  selectedImage = event.target;
  checkValues();
}

//Change the value of the selectedName and check the values
function selectName(event){
  selectedName = event.target;
  checkValues();
}


function checkValues() {
console.log(selectedImage);
console.log(selectedName);
//Check if both values are selected
  if (!selectedImage || selectedImage == 'undefined' || !selectedName || selectedName == 'undefined'){
    return ;
  }
//Check if values are equals
  if (selectedImage.value == selectedName.value) {
    alert("good");
//remove the button and the image
    selectedImage.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    selectedName.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    alert("no");
  }
//Reset the selected image and name.
  selectedImage = 'undefined';
  selectedName = 'undefined';
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <form>
        <label for="cow">
        <input type="radio" name="animals" id="cow" onclick="selectImage(event)" class="input-hidden" value="cow"/>
            <img src="images/cow.jpg" alt=""/>
        </label>

        <label for="dog">
        <input type="radio" name="animals" onclick="selectImage(event)" id="dog" class="input-hidden" value="dog"/>
            <img src="images/dog.jpg" alt=""/>
        </label>

        <label for="horse">
        <input type="radio" name="animals" onclick="selectImage(event)" id="horse" class="input-hidden" value="horse"/>
            <img src="images/horse.jpg" alt=""/>
        </label>

        <label for="pig">
        <input type="radio" name="animals" onclick="selectImage(event)" id="pig" class="input-hidden" value="pig"/>
            <img src="images/pig.jpg" alt=""/>
        </label>

    </form>

</div>     

    <div class="content">


<button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="dog" id="dog_t">Chien</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="cow" id="cow_t">Vache</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="pig" id="pig_t">Cochon</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="horse" id="horse_t">Cheval</button> 


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking ur time to answer my question.
bcz my images are there but they are not disappear unfortunately .if you could help me with that i really appreciate ur help .

Comment: Yep sry I forgot the images, I just edited my code so it deletes the images too.